# How can I pass a JSON object from HTML/Javascript to Python Flask using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I am developing a web-app and trying to send a JSON object (list of dictionaries) from a particular HTML page to my Flask/Python code.

I have found lots of posts on what the Python code is when processing a received JSON object. From my understanding, the code looks like something like this:

```
@app.route('/download/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def download():
    if request.is_json:
        data = request.get_json()
        # extract relevant details from data here
        return jsonify({"status":"success"})
```

HTML code looks something like this:

```
<h6>
    <a href="/download/" onclick="myFunction()">
        click here to download
    </a>
</h6>
```

JS code looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
        var dummy_data = [{"name": XYZ, "Age":21}, {"name": ABC, "Age":23}];
        var asJSON = JSON.stringify(dummy_data);
        // TODO: What should I do now?
    }
</script>
```

So from my understanding I have to use AJAX to communicate with Flask but I am unsure of how I have to do that. My second option seemed to be outdated in the form of XHTTP. If I am on the wrong track altogether, please suggest a better methodology altogether.

Much appreciated!

Comment: `fetch` is the best way to make Ajax requests in modern Javascript - there's a good introduction on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). (And loads of other resources elsewhere on the web.) If you prefer to use a library then [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) would be my recommendation.

Comment: this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Thank you, it worked without any troubles!